# Add special characters and Emoji to maill.app Menu bar

Tags: mail.app, internationalization

Mavericks has a wonderful and rich special characters and lots of Emojis to choose from.

[image: Emojis]

To call them up one has to press 3 keys (another keyboard short cut to remember :(

Is there a way to add this little app to let say Mail.app menu bar, so I just call it up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add it to the (os x) menubar by going to system preferences -> keyboard and checking "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar"

Comment: I forgot that i already have that one, was looking for something in Mail.app menu bar instead. But that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Once you add the Character Viewer to the menu bar as Kevin suggested you will be able to access the emoji characters from within the Character Viewer while inside of any app on MacOSX.

1 - Select Input Menu

[image: Select Input Menu]

2 - Select Character Viewer and choose Emoji (from within any app on OSX)

[image]

Comment: I have that one and already forgot about it, old age ?

Comment: Some companies take that functionality, repackage it and find buyers... The age old adage "if you know, then you know...:-)

Comment: I give you a point for your comment 